# How can I increase the speed of this FOR NEXT loop

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote this code over the weekend and it was blazing fast, when I got to work on Monday I sent an email before testing the code while servers had a load and it is infinitely slower. We are talking from 30 seconds to 15 minutes.

```
            For x = 3 To SRLastRow
            If Left(shMacro.Range("D" & x), 3) = "625" Then
                shMacro.Range("BW" & x) = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Arg1:=shMacro.Range("A" & x), Arg2:=WIPFile.Worksheets("Customer Master").Range("B:B"), Arg3:=WIPFile.Worksheets("Customer Master").Range("AD:AD"))
            Else
                shMacro.Range("BW" & x) = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Arg1:=shMacro.Range("A" & x), Arg2:=WIPFile.Worksheets("Customer Master").Range("B:B"), Arg3:=WIPFile.Worksheets("Customer Master").Range("AH:AH"))
            End If
            If shMacro.Range("BW" & x) <> shMacro.Range("BX" & x) Then
                shMacro.Range("BX" & x).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                ErrorCount = ErrorCount + 1
            End If
        Next x
```

I essentially need to pull in a value, then compare that pulled in value with a value on my Macro worksheet. If the values match do nothing, otherwise color the cell red.

I came up with the following, but haven't tested it fully yet, but the problem remains having to cycle through to find mismatches to color them.

```
            shMacro.Range("BW3").Formula = "=IF(LEFT(D3,3)=""625"",XLOOKUP(TEXT(A3,""000""),'[WORKBOOK]Customer Master'!$AD:$AD),XLOOKUP(TEXT(A3,""000""),'[WORKBOOK]Customer Master'!$B:$B,'[WORKBOOK]Customer Master'!$AH:$AH))"
            Range("BW3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("BW3:BW" & SRLastRow)
```

I've also tried looking into Arrays but I can't seem to figure those out. I think the autofill would be the fastest way to pull in the data, then somehow assign the two arrays (which would be columns BW and BX) and if they match do nothing, wherever they are different color BX + row reference red, and count the number of times it colored something red.

Comment: How many rows on the two sheets?

Comment: Well one basic way is have you tried turning off Events, Calculations & ScreenUpdating? They can make huge differences when working with the sheets directly.

Comment: You need to find out where the bottleneck is. Try stepping through the code in break mode and see if there are any particular statements that seem to be taking a long time (ie, a 1 sec or more).

Comment: +Tim Williams: shMacro is ~9000 but can fluctuate, WIPFile is ~3000
+Simon: I will try to turn off those, I assumed since not much was flickering it wouldn't have a huge impact.
+Nicholas Hunter: This code is definitely the bottle neck, I have a ton of other code that it blazes through, but then it gets to here and starts to drag.

Answer (score 0):

Should be a little faster (reducing cell reads without going "full array mode" and coloring all mismatches in one shot)

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim x As Long, SRLastRow As Long
    Dim colReturn As String, v, rngRed As Range, rw As Range
    
    '...
    '...
    '...
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For x = 3 To SRLastRow
        
        Set rw = shMacro.Rows(x)
        colReturn = IIf(Left(rw.Columns("D").Value, 3) = "625", "AD:AD", "AH:AH")
        
        v = Application.XLookup( _
                    Arg1:=rw.Columns("A").Value, _
                    Arg2:=WIPFile.Worksheets("Customer Master").Range("B:B"), _
                    Arg3:=WIPFile.Worksheets("Customer Master").Range(colReturn))
                          
        If Not IsError(v) Then
            rw.Columns("BW").Value = v
            With rw.Columns("BX")
                If v <> .Value Then
                    BuildRange rngRed, .Cells(1)
                    ErrorCount = ErrorCount + 1
                End If
            End With
        End If
    
    Next x
        
    'color the mismatches if any
    If Not rngRed Is Nothing Then rngRed.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        
End Sub

'utility - build a range using Union
Sub BuildRange(ByRef rngTot As Range, rngAdd As Range)
    If rngTot Is Nothing Then
        Set rngTot = rngAdd
    Else
        Set rngTot = Application.Union(rngTot, rngAdd)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for the slow processing is in the location of the WIPFile workbook. Therefore my code below minimizes the need to access it. I couldn't test my code for lack of data but I hope you will try it.

```
Sub Snippet()
    ' 214

    Dim LookUpRng   As Range            ' in "Customer Master"
    Dim ReturnVals  As Variant          ' values from "Customer Master"
    Dim C           As Long             ' Lookup column in ReturnRng
    Dim Fnd         As Range            ' search result
    Dim x           As Long             ' loop counter: rows (why "x" and not "R" ?)
    Dim ErrorCount  As Variant
    Dim Spike       As String           ' collect failed lookups
    
    ErrorCount = 0
    With WIPFile.Worksheets("Customer Master")
        Set LookUpRng = .Columns("BB")
        ReturnVals = .Range(.Columns("AD"), .Columns("AH")).Value
    End With
    
    With shMacro
        For x = 3 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Set Fnd = LookUpRng.Find(.Cells(x, "A").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If Fnd Is Nothing Then
                If Len(Spike) Then Spike = Spike & vbCr
                Spike = Spike & String(6, " ") & """" & .Cells(x, 1).Value & """ in row " & x
            Else
                C = IIf(Left(.Cells(x, "D").Value, 3) = "625", 1, 5)
                With .Cells(x, "BW")
                    .Value = ReturnVals(Fnd.Row, C)
                    If .Value <> .Cells(x, "BX").Value Then
                        .Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                        ErrorCount = ErrorCount + 1
                    End If
                End With
            End If
        Next x
    End With
    
    If Len(Spike) Then
        Spike = "The following look-ups were not successful." & vbCr & _
                Spike & IIf(ErrorCount, vbCr, "")
    Else
        Spike = "All look-ups were successful."
    End If
    If ErrorCount = 0 Then ErrorCount = "No"
    Spike = Spike & vbCr & ErrorCount & " matching error" & _
            IIf(ErrorCount = 1, "", "s") & " were highlighted."
    MsgBox Spike, vbInformation, "Action report"
End Sub
```

If my approach shows promise more speed could be gained by reading column B:B into another array and use a MATCH function instead of `Find`. In that way "Customer Master" would need to be accessed only once. Of course, you could also gain a little time by suspending `ScreenUpdating` during execution.

Answer (score 0):

No VBA required. Use Formula + Conditional formatting

**Entering the formula**

Put this formula in `BW3` and copy it down. Change `SAMPLE.xlsx` to the relevant file.

`=IF(LEFT(D3,3)=625,XLOOKUP(A3,'[SAMPLE.xlsx]Customer Master'!$B:$B,'[SAMPLE.xlsx]Customer Master'!$AD:$AD),XLOOKUP(A3,'[SAMPLE.xlsx]Customer Master'!$B:$B,'[SAMPLE.xlsx]Customer Master'!$AH:$AH))`

**Setting up Conditional Formatting**

1. Select the relevant range, starting for row 3.
2. Click on `Home` | `Conditional formatting` | `New Rule` | `Use formula to determine which cells to format`
3. Enter the formula `=BW3<>BX3` and set the relevant color.

   [image]

And you are done.

---

If you still want **VBA** then also you do not need any kind of loop or `Autofill`. You can enter the formula via VBA in all the cells in **1 GO**! Here is an example (**UNTESTED**)

```
With shMacro
    lrow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    .Range("BW3:BW" & lrow).Formula = "=IF(LEFT(D3,3)=625,XLOOKUP(A3,'[SAMPLE.xlsx]Customer Master'!$B:$B,'[SAMPLE.xlsx]Customer Master'!$AD:$AD),XLOOKUP(A3,'[SAMPLE.xlsx]Customer Master'!$B:$B,'[SAMPLE.xlsx]Customer Master'!$AH:$AH))"
End With
```

For conditional formatting you can use this code

```
With shMacro.Range("BW3:BW" & lrow)
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=BW3<>BX3"
    .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

    With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End With
```

So basically your entire code can be written as

```
With shMacro
    lrow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    With .Range("BW3:BW" & lrow)
        .Formula = "=IF(LEFT(D3,3)=625,XLOOKUP(A3,'[SAMPLE.xlsx]Customer Master'!$B:$B,'[SAMPLE.xlsx]Customer Master'!$AD:$AD),XLOOKUP(A3,'[SAMPLE.xlsx]Customer Master'!$B:$B,'[SAMPLE.xlsx]Customer Master'!$AH:$AH))"
        DoEvents
        
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=BW3<>BX3"
        .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    
        With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 255
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    End With
End With
```